# Get all subfolders of a file path android kotlin

Tags: android, file, kotlin

Lets say that i have a file path like the following

```
data/com.myapp.testapp/direcotry_1/directory_2/directory_3/image.jpg
```

Is there any extension function that can print me the following?

```
direcotry_1
direcotry_2
direcotry_3
```

meaning all the subfolders that the filepath contains?

Comment: new File("/data/com.myapp.testapp/direcotry_1/directory_2/directory_3/image.jpg").getParent().getParent() and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `String` methods to split your path

```
String path = "data/com.myapp.testapp/direcotry_1/directory_2/directory_3/image.jpg";
String[] splitted = path.split("/");
```

Then, you can browse the resulted array.

Note: you can remove the first part, ie "data/package_name", with the use of `indexOf()` or `subString()`